# yii2 REST authentication keeps its authentication information

Tags: rest, authentication, cookies, yii2

Iam working on a REST module in Yii2. The client is able to authenticate on the server and is also able to get the requested response. I have seen, that the client authenticates one time to the system. It seems that the client stores its authentication information, because no further authentication for following requests is needed.

Of course, Iam interested that each REST request needs an authentication. I have seen, that there could be one way to do some fixed settings in the configuration of the app, which I would like to avoid.

I guess that the authentication information is stored in a cookie. I assume that the cookie is named'_csrf-frontend'. Now I try to remove this cookie within a controller function.

```
$cookies = \Yii::$app->response->cookies;
$cookies->remove('_csrf-frontend');
unset($cookies['_csrf-frontend']);
```

I've added additionaly recommended settings of Idgs answer, but still no luck. After a refresh of the page the authentication information must be kept, because still no authentication is necessary.

A look in the Headers shows:

```
Response Header:
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date    Thu, 29 Mar 2018 06:36:37 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie  _csrf-frontend=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; HttpOnly _identity-frontend=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding   chunked

Request Header:
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Authorization   Basic ZG9yaXMua3JhdXNAdmVydHJlbmQuY29tOktyYXVzMTAwMA==
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  eafab809c11b0a847c07e9c4f2b93936=uv3f1tof6la24616p7bkf59p55; advanced-frontend=mobbni6v6492kde73amtdvcqi3; _csrf-frontend=4d2ddb54290d2fa7fcc9c4a9900726b795e83aadc658fc0f50395bf7ded0c86aa%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A14%3A%22_csrf-frontend%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22Oiy_JOiLMg_X0Hz666f0OWpG_r-jcvnO%22%3B%7D
DNT 1
Host    localhost
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests   1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0
```

Only, if I remove all of the Browsers Chronik in Firefox, then a new authentication request is coming up.

Comment: If you are only doing HTTP Basic authentication, the browser is probably saving the credentials (perhaps where the Authorization header is coming from above).

Comment: Yes, right now there is only HTTP Basic authentification. Do you mean that is not enough? Can I take influence in case that the browser is saving the login credentials? I mean delete this information, or prevent from savin the credentials?

Comment: It just explains why that behavior is happening in the browser. You can search for this issue as there are many posts on it ("_Chrome saves basic auth creds, etc_"). There isn't anything particularly wrong with Basic auth if it meets your requirements. For more info, see posts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968009/api-design-http-basic-authentication-vs-api-token

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not the CSRF feature that's setting the login cookie, see: [rest-authentication docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-authentication), which tells you how to disable the login session.

#### Disable Sessions

If you don't want to use the recommended *config* settings:

```
'user' => [
    'enableSession' => false,
    'enableAutoLogin' => false,
```

You can set the values in your *controller* like:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    Yii::$app->user->enableSession = false;
    Yii::$app->user->loginUrl = null;
}
```

#### Disable CSRF

If you also want to turn off CSRF (e.g., if you have any web form POSTS to your API), either update the `request` component in your web *config* like:

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'enableCsrfValidation' => false,
```

or to turn CSRF off in your *controller*, use:

```
$this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

(Obviously you would want to implement your own CSRF protection as applicable if you do turn it off.)

Comment: I've tried all your recommendations, including a combination of them (excl. the configuration settings), but it is not working. A refresh of the page, keeps the authentication alive, no authentication necessary. I add the Response Header and Request Header and update the question.